# Rounded corner for the code listing

Tags: listings, rounded-corners

Is it possible to make a rounded corner for the tex code listing? Given:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %used for font color
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{White},
     language=Java,
     tabsize=1,
     keywordstyle=\color{Red}\bf,
     showstringspaces=false,
     morekeywords={public, class}
 }

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
      arc=0pt,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=black,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      hbox
}

\begin{mylisting}
public class MyObject{

    public MyObject(){
        System.out.println("MyObject");
    }
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

I would like to make a rounded corner. This code will be included in a  presentation, and although only a cosmetics issue, it looks much appealing when you have nice rounded corners and shadows. Is it possible to do in in Latex?

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy. Would you post as an answer Harish?

Comment: user3232: I have added some shadow for you. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option `arc` is provided for this purpose. You have set it to `0pt`. Change its value to say some thing like `5mm` (say). Further, you can add shadows with `enhanced` option and `skins` library of `tcolorbox`. The syntax would be

```
shadow={<xshift>}{<yshift>}{<offset>}{<options>}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %used for font color
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}        %%% skins needed for shadow

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{White},
     language=Java,
     tabsize=1,
     keywordstyle=\color{Red}\bf,
     showstringspaces=false,
     morekeywords={public, class}
 }

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
      enhanced,                             %%% needed for shadow
      arc=5mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=black,
      shadow={5mm}{-3mm}{0mm}{fill=black!50!white,
                      opacity=0.5},             %%% here for shadow  and adjust as you like
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      hbox
}

\begin{mylisting}
public class MyObject{

    public MyObject(){
        System.out.println("MyObject");
    }
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}    
\lstset{frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR}}   
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,breaklines,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily]{P04-Tk.py}
from tkinter import *                     # import Tkinter module

root = Tk()                               # create Tk root widget

root.mainloop()                           # enter Tkinter event loop
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And for a double line: `\lstset{frameshape={ryrRYR}{yY}{yY}{ryrRYR}}`

[image]